# How can I set PusherClient into a Rails initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, initializer

At https://github.com/logankoester/pusher-client how can I put the settings into a rails initializer in `config/initializers/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `pusher.rb` in `config/initialisers` and add your pusher config there, something like:

```
Pusher.app_id = 'your-pusher-app-id'
Pusher.key = 'your-pusher-key'
Pusher.secret = 'your-pusher-secret'
```

The full docs for the gem can be found here: http://rubydoc.info/github/pusher/pusher-gem/master/frames